# How to print json to console in plugin using MessageConsoleStream

Tags: java, json, eclipse, plugins

I'm creating a plugin for eclipse that takes JSON from the Web of Trust API and prints it into the console. I was able to print the entire JSON but when I try to get specific information, it will not show up in the plugin console.

```
try {

JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://api.mywot.com/0.4/public_link_json2?hosts=google.com/&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            JSONObject msg = (JSONObject) json.getJSONObject("google.com").getJSONObject("categories");
            String[] parts = msg.toString().split(",");
            String[] parts2 = parts[1].split(":");


           // System.out.println("Score:" + parts2[0]);
        //System.out.println("Score:" + parts2[0]);
      //print result
        MessageConsoleStream out = ConsoleManager.getMessageConsoleStream( "Console" );
        out.println("Score:" + msg.toString());

    }
 catch (Exception e) {

} 

    return null;
}





private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        try {
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
          String jsonText = readAll(rd);
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
          return json;
        } finally {
          is.close();
        }
}
```

ConsoleManager Class:

```
public class ConsoleManager {

 public static MessageConsole findConsole( String name )  {
        ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
        IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();
        IConsole[] existing = conMan.getConsoles();
        for ( int i = 0; i < existing.length; i++ )
            if ( name.equals( existing[i].getName() ) ) return ( MessageConsole ) existing[i];
        //no console found, so create a new one
        MessageConsole myConsole = new MessageConsole( name, null );
        conMan.addConsoles( new IConsole[]{myConsole} );
        return myConsole;
    }

    public static MessageConsoleStream getMessageConsoleStream( String name ) {
        MessageConsole myConsole = findConsole( name );
        MessageConsoleStream out = myConsole.newMessageStream();
        return out;
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to print the value from the JSON stored in parts2, however when I try to print it to the plugin console, it doesn't show anything. No errors so I think I'm missing something.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is your console the one that is currently being shown?

You probably want to call `IConsoleManager.showConsoleView(console)` to show your console.

Comment: I think so, I've displayed values on the console before. Within the instance of eclipse the console is shown, its just there is no output.